# How to write Regex for pattern like a series of Number and String pair separated by Space. Pattern -> n <space> string

Tags: c#, regex

Consider a pattern:

7 "Fault" 6 "Reserved" 2 "Running" 1 "Cranking" 0 "Stop"

I want to write a Regex for building a key value pair using number as the key and string next to it as Value.

So for above example, I want my output as:

> - ## Key Value
> - 7   Fault
> - 6   Reserved
> - 2   Running
> - 1   Cranking
> - 0   Stop

Comment: `[0-9]+\s\"[A-Za-z]+\"` pattern - one or more digits, followed by white space, followed by enquoted text (One or more letters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "7 \"Fault\" 6 \"Reserved\" 2 \"Running\" 1 \"Cranking\" 0 \"Stop\"";
            string pattern = "(?'key'\\d+)\\s+\"(?'value'[^\"]+)\"";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

            foreach (Match match in matches.Cast<Match>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", match.Groups["key"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value); 
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```